# How can I move my Selenium chrome driver to the PATH on Windows 10?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, path

I have been trying to set up selenium, python, and whenever I test the code it says that the files must be in path, and I don't know how to move it there. This is the error I get:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWsLw.png

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you downloaded the chrome driver form this [link](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads),
you need to put that executable file named `chromedriver.exe` preferably in your project folder or you can put it in desktop for example or anywhere,
now you copy the path (wich is the location of `chromedriver.exe`) and paste as following : 
 `driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')`

 here is an example if I put chromedriver.exe in my desktop folder in windows :

`driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\asmoun\\Desktop\\chromedriver')`

 PS : use double back slash `\\` or one forward slash `'/'`